# How do I output the file size along with the output of files?

Tags: bash, disk-usage

I wrote a script that searches for a file then outputs it. This script has worked up until the point where I tried using the `du` command. the code is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter either file name or format:"
    read File

echo "Input the absolute path to directory:"
    read Dir

echo "Enter \"/path/to/directory/filename\" to store outputs on the filename:"
    read results

#cd $Dir; 
#for dir in */; do 
#   echo $Dir; 
#done | xargs -P0 -I_ echo "sudo find _ -type f -name \*$File\* " > temp.txt

cd $Dir; 
for dir in */; do 
  echo $dir; 
done | xargs -P0 -I_ sudo find _ -type f -name \*$File\* | du >> $results
```

Basically it searches the directory you wish to search for the file you inputted, and `xargs` is there to utilize as many cores as possible.

I only need now to output the size of the file along with the files that will be outputted to the `results` file. doing this myself gives me the wrong output which consists of every directory, and does not find the files I search for instead. Any ideas?

Comment: @bu5hman original it was a one-liner

Comment: Effectively it still is (all `;` are still there) though since it is in a script it makes little odds except in readability. Am sure OP will let me know if the readability edit contradicts the intent and I will roll back.

Comment: @bu5hman Thanks for making it more readable its absolutely fine, no need to change back.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has some bugs

```
cd $Dir
```

should not used in script because `cd` may fail but your script is continuing (and will fail for spaces in folder name). better do a check if `cd` was successful, two examples:

```
cd "$Dir" || exit 2
cd "$Dir" && for dir in */; do
```

`sudo` should not used in script. better run the script with right permissions (just opinion)

```
sudo find _ -type f -name \*$File\*
```

`find` can be placed inside the loop if loop is requirement, no need for `xargs` (opinion)

```
for dir in */; do echo $dir; done
```

the for loop makes less sense (because it's nothing inside) and could just replaced with `ls -d */`. it will just print subfolders (excluded hidden starting with `.`) even `find */` directly will work (better `cd "$Dir" && find ./*/`)

```
\*$File\* | du >> $results
```

don't pipe a string to `du` it will not do what you expect. give file names as arguments, you can do this with `xargs` or better use find `-exec` (terminated with `\;` for processing each file on its own, or with `+` for passing all file names as argument at once)

```
for dir in */; find "$dir" -type f -iname "*$File*" -exec du {} + >> "$results"; done
```

---

However, instead of running `find` on subfolders `"$dir"` you could just run it straight on parent `"$Dir"` with `-mindepth 2` and for file size i recommend using `stat` with desired output, for example `stat -c %s$'\t'%n` (except you really want to have disk usage instead)

```
find "$Dir" -mindepth 2 -type f -iname "*$File*" -exec stat -c %s$'\t'%n {} + >> "$results"
```

or with `xargs -0` if too many arguments passed to `stat`

```
find "$Dir" -mindepth 2 -type f -iname "*$File*" -print0 | xargs -0 -P0 stat -c %s$'\t'%n >> "$results"
```

for a more safe way to process folder names i recommend find while read loop with NUL terminated results (GNU extension `-print0`) see this answers for reference (although with `xargs -I_ find _` you have found a working solution)

[How to loop through file names returned by find?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37210472)